# Can't use absolute URL in a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the following script for a halloween effect tomorrow : https://auz.github.io/Bug/

The problem is that it keeps searching for the files in the HOME directory (mysite.com/fly-sprite.png)

I am using wordpress multisite and have all sorts of changes in my htaccess file.

Despite changing `imageSprite: 'fly-sprite.png'` to `'mysite/flysprite.png'` I am still stuck with console 404 errors pointing to the home directory to look for these files.

How can I edit the Javascript to use an absolute URL?

https://jsfiddle.net/3pfcdb97/

Comment: Try `'https://mysite/flysprite.png'`. Without the `http://` / `https://` prefix, it's still looking for a relative URL

Comment: @Phil Nope, nothing. Keeps looking for it in the home directory.

Comment: Clear your cache and try again

Comment: Isn't it so, that Wordpress has a some configuration settings that define the path for scripts. I suppose you've to make changes to the configuration files.

Comment: @Phil the issue was I kept the my-site.com before the rest of the path. You solved it. Thank you!!!